# Give a unique ID while saving

Tags: custom-post-types, id

I have in my theme custom post types (products) with some meta-boxes.
My client asked me, to automaticly give a unique SKU (meta-box) while saving that product.

My thought:

> Give a random ID => have to check if that ID somewhere else exists OR
>
> Give the Post-ID => that is just possible after saving once, cuz WP assign that ID while saving.

**@Milo**
"additionally, a new post already has an ID before the user saves the post"
How can I get the ID before I save the post and put it into that meta box and save it with a new post at once?

Thanks

Comment: Post IDs are already unique. Why is that not sufficient?

Comment: additionally, a new post already has an ID before the user saves the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [add a meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), the post object is passed to the function that outputs your meta box content, and the ID is immediately available. Here's a quick proof-of-concept that will put the ID in a field in a post meta box when creating a new post:

```
function wpd_sku_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'wpd_sku',
        'SKU',
        'wpd_render_meta_box',
        'post'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpd_sku_meta_box' );

function wpd_render_meta_box( $post ) {
    // $post->ID contains the ID of newly created post:
    echo '<input type="text" id="wpd_sku" name="wpd_sku" value="' . $post->ID . '">';
}

function wpd_sku_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return $post_id;

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['wpd_sku'] ) )
        return $post_id;

    $sku = $_POST['wpd_sku'];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wpd_sku', $sku );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpd_sku_save' );
```

but please don't use this code as-is, start with the example on the [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) codex page, which has some nonce and permission checks.